# preferredLanguages iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, localization, ios9

in order to localize my App, I use the following code:

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];  
             if ([language isEqualToString:@"fr"]) {  
}else{  
}
```

But since iOS 9, I'have to replace "fr" by "fr-FR". The problem is that only works for France. How can I support all the other regions (Canada, Belgium,..) ? and the "general setting" for french ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `language` is returning other values such a "fr-FR" and "fr-CA", then you should split `language` on the `-` character. This will work even you simply get "fr".

```
NSString *firstLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
NSString *language = [[firstLanguage componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] firstObject];
if ([language isEqualToString:@"fr"]) {
} else {
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this solution, since it may not work as expected for Chinese. zh-Hans-US would result in zh, whereas the language is zh-Hans. Better cut off at the last appearance of "-".

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't split the NSLocale. NSLocale has some Keys, which you can retrieve with `objectForKey:`

In your example you can write the following:

```
[[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode]
            isEqualToString:@"fr"]
```

`[NSLocale currentLocale]` is actually the same as `[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject]` but has some additional information where you can retrieve which decimal separator should be used or which currency symbol.

Other relevant Keys can be found in the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/index.html) from apple.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there Don't do like that It will create issue when localization are set different for language having different regions as like `es-mx` and `es-cl`. In that case above solution will create issue. 
Use following code for the solution:

```
NSString *selectedLanguage = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0];
```

In case your have selected `zh-Hans-US` from setting But your app is having `zh-Hans-TW` and `zh-Hans-CN` only. That the above code will return you **`"zh-Hans-TW"`** the first preferred Localization.

Try this may be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Paste my codes in here, maybe help you

```
- (NSString *)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key withDefault:(NSString *)defaultString
{
    static NSBundle *bundle = nil;
    if (bundle == nil)
    {
        NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_resources" ofType:@"bundle"];
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath] ?: [NSBundle mainBundle];
        //manually select the desired lproj folder
        for (NSString *language in [NSLocale preferredLanguages])
        {
            for (NSString *loc in [bundle localizations] ) {
                if ([language hasPrefix:loc])
                {
                    bundlePath = [bundle pathForResource:loc ofType:@"lproj"];
                    bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
                    goto getString;
                }
            }
        }
    }
getString:
    defaultString = [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:defaultString table:nil];
    return [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:key value:defaultString table:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix on my code is simple :

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSRange range = [language rangeOfString:@"-" options:NSBackwardsSearch];
NSString * languageMark = [language substringToIndex:range.location];
```