# IOS What's the best and safe way to check the phone language?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

Until now i have used this code to retrive phone language:

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

As we already now, apple since IOS 9 has changed the return of this function, from something like "en" to something like "en-GB".In my apps i usually do an "istostring" to check with wich language i have to work.
Now i need to implement something like the correct answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32800537/3057259)

And i have to implement a condition in every method call to check if the device is IOS <9 or IOS >=9. This apple's change seems to not consider any older version compatility problems,i made an intensive use of this function, so i have to update all my apps...Maybe the problem is another, there's a better way to check the actual language of the phone?

Comment: Actually Apple changed back to the old ways of iOS 3, which used to distinguish language and region in the localization string.
Eg you could get results for Italian as IT-it for Italian as spoken in Italy and IT-ch for Italian as spoken in Switzerland.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, its a common pain shared by developer community and there is nothing much we can do to address this.

However, I safeguard myself by adding a category on `UIDevice` like this:

```
+ (NSString *)deviceLanguage {
    return [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Then simply call:

```
[UIDevice deviceLanguage]
```

to get the device language. At least, like in your case, if you are using this feature multiple places, there is only one place change to make the entire app align to new language/OS support.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this might help you

```
NSArray *array = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
for (NSString *lan in array) 
{

 NSLog(@"%@: %@ %@",lan, [NSLocale canonicalLanguageIdentifierFromString:lan], [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:lan] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:lan]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Objective C

```
NSString *language = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] objectAtIndex:0];
```

In Swift

```
let language = NSBundle.mainBundle().preferredLocalizations.first! as NSString
```

Comment: It will not give device language.It will give the language you have given in app.i.e The gives the language that you have given in CFBundleDevelopmentRegion of info.plist if CFBundleAllowMixedLocalizations is true in info.plist then first item of CFBundleLocalizations in info.plist is returned