# Multi-language icons cannot display on iOS 9

Tags: ios, localization, ios9

I inserted some different languages pictures into images.
I used the code below to judge what language is used on device then display  corresponding language icon. 
The icon didn't display on iOS 9 device and I couldn't find why.
But they did display on iOS 8 device.

```
NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([language isEqualToString:@"fr"])
{
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"xxxxxxxxx"]];
}

else if ([language isEqualToString:@"fr"])
{...
}

else 
{...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [preferredLanguages iOS 9](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32800410/preferredlanguages-ios-9)

Comment: I tried but i still cannot work.